# How to make a service "fail" or restart

Tags: windows, windows-services

I'm trying to hack up a way to deal with some programming issues by having my Windows service shutdown and restart itself (don't ask why, that's another topic). I see in the properties for the service, I can set it to restart on the 1st, 2nd, and subsequent failures.  How do I make it "fail" in my code (besides doing something like overwriting memory, etc.)?  I figured I could call SetServiceStatus() and set dWin32ExitCode to ERROR_SERVICE_SPECIFIC_ERROR and dwServiceSpecificExitCode to some number, but that doesn't do the trick.  Any ideas?  Or is there some other way to restart a service without user intervention?

Answer (score 0):

Well, just doing an exit(1) seems to work.